# Which is the best in performance having 1 to many relationships on tables

Tags: php, mysql, json, database

I have a table **company** in which I am saving company information and I want to save **N number of company locations for that particular company** (country_id, city_id). **1** company has **Multiple** locations. I have to save country and city in database in such a way that if user wants to view company **filter by Country** or **filter by city**, it will search very fast (*Indexing applied*).

Which option will give me better performance in terms of fast search, Normalization?

Option 1: 
Should I maintain country id and city id in JSON and save it in Company table?
No need of new table. every time I will add or update JSON based on users selections.

for e.g.

```
[{"country1" : {city1, city2, city3}}, 
 {"country3" : {city5, city1, city3}}]
```

Then I can (LIKE) query on this field -> decode json -> return result

option 2: 
Should I create new table and save country's and city's PK along with

```
company_id FK.

company_id (FK) | country id | city id

1 | 25 | 12
1 | 25 | 16
1 | 25 | 19
1 | 30 | 1
1 | 30 | 69
1 | 30 | 14
```

then just query and return result

Comment: Normalization is best

Comment: You will face a lot of issues with un-normalized data and the top most would be CRUD anomalies, `LIKE` would slow your search...

Comment: i have 8.9 millions records.....

Comment: Are you trying to say that saving data in JSON would reduce number of records and search will be faster?

Comment: Is it mysql or sql server? can't be both...

Comment: @ZoharPeled it truly can't be both. But trying to work with denormalized data is a terrible idea in both MySQL and MSSQL Server.

Comment: @OllieJones I completely agree. This is why I wrote my answer before even asking this question. However, people should tag questions properly, even if the answer suits more then one rdbms...

Comment: @ZoharPeled those of us with edit privilege can edit the tags. That's what I did here.

Answer (score 2):

Normalize if you're using traditional SQL.

MongoDB and other similar systems for storing hierarchical data (MarkLogic, etc) have ways of making the search of JSON docs fast.

But searching and updating denormalized data is an unreliable pain in the neck in SQL. With the volume you have, it will be very slow.

Comment: Am using mysql innodb

Answer (score 2):

Option #2, meaning creating a separate table for company location is the best option.  Use the combination of all 3 columns to create the primary key as a clustered index.

Never, under any circumstances, will a delimited value column be more efficient then lookup tables in a relational database. the cost of using `Like` or parsing the data (not to mention if you are using the like operator to get more results then needed and then parse the data in code) is always higher then the cost of querying a well indexed normalized tables with a simple inner join.

Comment: yup, have just started on op 2.  looking for more accuracy on option 2

Comment: What else do you need to know?